# Show some characters above a picture on hover

Tags: css

I would like to show a word above a picture that has a filter on hover.

I'm trying to do this with `:before` but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<p><a class="photo" href="image.jpg"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></p>
```

CSS

```
.photo { position: relative; }
.photo:hover { filter: brightness(0.5); -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5); -moz-filter: brightness(0.5); z-index: 9; }
.photo:hover:after { content: "test"; font-family: "arial"; position: absolute; height: 50px; width: 50px; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 99; color: #fff; font-size: 50px; opacity: 0; }
```

Here is the JSFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/

How to resolve this ?

Comment: i would suggest adding the text with opacity 0 all the time.. then show it on hover.. like so http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/1/

Comment: Thank you ! http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/4/ Is it possible to get the text totally white ?

Comment: change your hover state to a block element rather than effecting the `a` element itself, also best to make the `a` `inline-block`.. see here http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the opacity in `.photo:hover:after` to 1:

```
.photo {
    position: relative;
}

.photo:hover{
    filter: brightness(0.5); -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5); -moz-filter: brightness(0.5); z-index: 9;
}

.photo:hover:after { content: "test"; font-family: "arial"; position: absolute; height: 50px; width: 50px; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 99; color: #fff; font-size: 50px; opacity: 1; }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you wrote "opacity: 0;", which sets the opacity of the text to 0 - making it invisible. Just take that css property out and you'll see the text.

Also, this normally doesn't matter and is a bit nit picky, but you generally want to use "::after" instead of ":after".

Answer (score 1):

Please try this : http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/8/

```
    <div><a class="photo" href="http://www.sticker-autocollant.com/3769-4997-large/stickers-geant-deco-vue-sur-la-mer-et-montagne.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.sticker-autocollant.com/3769-4997-large/stickers-geant-deco-vue-sur-la-mer-et-montagne.jpg" />
        <div class="hover_text"> Hover me</div>
    </a></div>


.photo , div{
   float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
    .hover_text{    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    bottom: 4px;    
        width: 100%; display:none;transition: all 0.5s ease-in;}
    div:hover .hover_text{display:block; transition: all 0.5s ease-in;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update your css as below, opacity and position of text to change for expacted result.

```
   .photo {
    position: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 30ms;
    -moz-transition: all 30ms;
    transition: all 30ms;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.photo:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.5); -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5); -moz-filter: brightness(0.5); z-index: 9;
}

.photo:after { content: "test"; font-family: "arial"; position: absolute; height: 50px; width: 50px; top: 30%; left: 20%; z-index: 99; color: #fff; font-size: 50px; opacity: 0; }
.photo:hover:after{ opacity:1; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the text in "real" white, as if `opacity:1;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are several things to do here in order to accomplish what you want.

- Remove `opacity: 0` which prevents text from displaying.
- Move `position: relative` to parent element, `<p>`.
- Set `<p>` to `inline-block` so it doesn't have full width of container and position will work more like expected.

---

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.test img:hover {
filter: brightness(0.5); -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5); -moz-filter: brightness(0.5);
}

.photo:hover:after { 
content: "test"; font-family: "arial"; width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; 
top: 40%; left: 40%; color: #fff; font-size: 50px;
}
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/13/

Comment: Thank you. Would it possible to get the text in "full" white ?

Comment: What do you mean by full white?

Comment: At the moment, the text appears in grey, I presume it's because of the opacity ?

Comment: I see the text as white in the fiddle, may be some of your other css causing that.

Comment: Yes, this is because of the brightness filter on `.photo:hover`. Is it possible to apply the filter on the picture and not on the text ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution. [**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5j90ccn/9/), `Opacity` should be greater then 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by simply adding a title attribute on your image tag. Like following:

```
<a class="photo" href="image.jpg"><img src="image.jpg" Title="This is where your word go" /></a>
```